# Finding the number of up and down votes for a given tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, down-votes, up-votes

I apologize if this has already been asked but is there a way to find out how many up and down votes a user has for a given tag?

Comment: So which gold badge are you waiting for? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you'll need to use the public Data Dump.

The closest you have is [the Stats tab of each tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=discussion&sort=stats&pagesize=50).